# About scope of arguments and document.writeln in function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm reading "JavaScripts The Good Parts"(by Douglas Crockford). It's good.
I can not understand following code. It's working correctly. But I can not understand how it works.
There are 5 questions about this code.

1. values of arguments (I checked them as [A], [B] in comment)
2. reason that document.writeln does not work(i.e. show nothing) in function (I checked test position as [C], [D] in comment)
3. result of slice in this code (in [A], [B])
4. values of variable args (in [A], [B])
5. reason that document.writeln shows 'undefined' (in comment [E] )

After showing that code, I will explain more.

```
var myTest = {};

Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
  if(!this.prototype[name])
  {
    this.prototype[name]=func;
  }
};

Function.method('bind', function(that) {
  var method = this,
  slice = Array.prototype.slice,
  args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]);    //[A] value of arguments and args 

  //-------------------------------
  //[C] following document.writeln do not work. why?
  document.writeln("<C>arguments[0]:", arguments[0]);
  document.writeln("<C>arguments[1]:", arguments[1]);
  document.writeln("<C>args:",args);
  myTest.str1 = 1;
  myTest.str2 = "ABC";
  document.writeln("<C>str1:", myTest.str1);
  document.writeln("<C>str2:", myTest.str2);
  //-------------------------------

  return function(){

     //-------------------------------
     //[D] following document.writeln do not work. why?
     document.writeln("<D>arguments[0]:", arguments[0]);
     document.writeln("<D>arguments[1]:", arguments[1]);
     document.writeln("<D>args:",args);
     myTest.str3 = 2;
     myTest.str4 = "DEF";
     document.writeln("<D>str3:", myTest.str3);
     document.writeln("<D>str4:", myTest.str4);
     //-------------------------------

      return method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0])));    //[B] value of arguments and args 
    };
  });

var x= function(){
  return this.value;
}.bind({value:666});

//-------------------------------
document.writeln("str1:", myTest.str1, "<br/>");   //[E]show undefined. why?
document.writeln("str2:", myTest.str2, "<br/>");   //[E]show undefined. why?
document.writeln("str3:", myTest.str3, "<br/>");   //[E]show undefined. why?
document.writeln("str4:", myTest.str4, "<br/>");   //[E]show undefined. why?
//-------------------------------

alert(x());    //666 -> no problem
```

document.writeln in [C], [D], [E] was for testing. But they don't work as I expected.
Alerting '666' operates well. (No problem)

Help me, please...

----------- after removing if-confition in Function.prototype.method I got following result

```
[C]arguments[0]:[object Object]
[C]arguments[1]:undefined
[C]args:
[C]str1:1
[C]str2:ABC
str0C:[object Object]
str1C:undefined
str0D:undefined
str1D:undefined
str1:1
str2:ABC
str3:undefined
str4:undefined
[D]arguments[0]:undefined
[D]arguments[1]:undefined
[D]args:
[D]str1:2
[D]str2:DEF
str0C:[object Object]
str1C:undefined
str0D:undefined
str1D:undefined
str1:1
str2:ABC
str3:2
str4:DEF
```

Now, I wonder real value of arguments in [C], [D], the contents of array...

Using JSON.stringify(arguments[0])), I finally got the real value of arguments.

```
[C]arguments[0]:{"value":666}
```

This is what I really want.
[C]arguments[1], [D]arguments[0], [D]arguments[1] do not have values. So they are 'undefined', right.

Now, I want to know what "args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]);" does in [A].

```
args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
```

As I know, slice returns copy of array. Because we use apply, slice works using arguments as this, and [1] as array of argument.  At this time, arguments have only one item {"value":666"}.  slice(start, end) returns copy of array which starts from 'start' and ends with 'end'.  Then, in this case slice.apply(arguments, [1]) must return copy of arguments which starts from 1.  But as we know arguments have only 1 item, so arguments[1] does not exist.(arguments[0], {value:666} exists.)  Then how this work?  args is undefined.  What does this do?  Is there anything that I overlooked?

In [B] it returns "method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0])));".

```
return method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0])));
```

In this, [0] is array of argument.  0..  Why zero?  And arguments is undefined.  Um...  Then this returns arguments[0]?  And that is {value:666}?  And alert '666'?

---

I got it..

arguments in [A] is arguments of bind function

arguments in [B] is arguments of x function

Right?

Now there is one (maybe last) question .. ^^
When I call document.writeln.bind(document,"TEST") ,  what is 'that' in Function.method('bind', function(that)?

'that' is document?  or 'that' is [document, "TEST"]

Comment: I fixed some spelling errors

Comment: I added additional question to my post. I wonder the real contents of arguments in [C], [D]

Comment: I added additional questions to my post^^;; I wonder why [1], [0] are used in apply function

Comment: maybe last question...^^ I added that at the end of post. (when I call document.writeln.bind(document,"TEST"),  what is that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
>     if(!this.prototype[name])
> ```

…is your problem. You're not overwriting existing functions - and [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does already exist (and has the same result as the one you defined, but without logging). That way, you don't overwrite it with your custom implementation, and none of your `document.writeln` calls or `myTest` assignments will be executed.

You can remove the if-condition for test purposes, and it will work. You should be able to answer the other questions yourself, once you see in the output what happens.

---

> Now, I wonder real value of arguments in [C], [D], the contents of array...

There's only one object in question: `{value:666}` :-) You can output that by using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
document.writeln("<C>arguments[0]:", JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
…
```

---

> [slicing] Then, in this case slice.apply(arguments, [1]) must return copy of arguments which starts from 1.

Yes. Btw it would've been easier to write `slice.call(arguments, 1)` - they're the same.

> But as we know arguments have only 1 item, so arguments[1] does not exist.(arguments[0], {value:666} exists.) Then how this work? args is undefined.

Not `undefined`, but the empty array `[]`.

> What does this do? Is there anything that I overlooked?

It takes further, optional arguments to `bind`. You didn't pass any.

> In [B] it returns "method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0])));". In this, [0] is array of argument. 0.. Why zero?

Because you want to get all of the (optional) arguments to the bound function - slicing them from the beginning.

> And arguments is undefined. Um... Then this returns arguments[0]? And that is {value:666}? And alert '666'?

`arguments` is not undefined, but has length 0, so the whole `args.concat(…)` evaluates to an empty array. `that` still points to the `{value: 666}`, yes - it is what will be passed for the `this` keyword.

So what are all these optional arguments about?

In your `x` example you've only used `this`, your function did not really have any arguments. But it could have - let's try one that has more arguments, like `console.log`:

```
var logger = console.log.bind(console, "Here:");
logger(); // Here:
logger(5); // Here: 5
logger({value:666}); // Here: {value: 666}
```

If you're not (yet) comfortable with the console, you could equally use `document.writeln.bind(document, …`.

Comment: Thank you^^ I have additional questions.As you say Function.prototype.method already exist. Then, in my opinion, Function.method('bind', function(that)) must work using "already existing" Function.method. But it didn't work. Of course, when I remove if-condition document.writeln works well.

Comment: Yes, `Function.method('bind', …)` lets the original method untouched. The already existing function *does* work - you're alerting 666 in the end as expected.

Comment: You are right ^^;; I added additional questions to my post. I wonder why [1], [0] are used in apply function

Comment: I god it..^^ arguments in [A] is arguments of bind.  arguments in [B] is arguments of x. Right?  I have other (maybe last) question...^^ I added that at the end of post. (when I call document.writeln.bind(document,"TEST"),  what is that?)

Comment: The `that` parameter is where you pass the `document` in, so that it becomes the "[`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the `writeln` function" - so that it behaves the same as a *method* call `document.writeln(…)` :-)

Comment: I thought 'bind' function receive only one argument(that), so 'bind' receive one argument from document.writeln(document, "TEST") - the first(document).  so that = document. This inference is Right?  When I print that value using document.writeln("[D]that:",that,"<br/>") , I got [object Document].

Comment: Yes, one `that` argument and further, optional `args` arguments.